# Export Item-wise stock summary from Tally ERP 9

Tags: tally

I am working with Tally ERP 9 (Accounting software) for export stock summary report.

I am able to export stock summary report through below xml request

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
<TYPE>Data</TYPE>
<ID>Stock Summary</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
       <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Global Trading Corporation</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Now My question is How to export Stock Summary -> F5(Item-wise)  report using xml request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get Item Wise Stock Summary by by setting 'IsItemWise' variable as 'Yes'.

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
<TYPE>Data</TYPE>
<ID>Stock Summary</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
       <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Global Trading Corporation</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
</STATICVARIABLES>
<TDL>
  <TDLMESSAGE>
   <REPORT NAME="Stock Summary" ISMODIFY="Yes" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
    <SET>IsItemWise: Yes</SET>
   </REPORT>
  </TDLMESSAGE>
</TDL>
</DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: This worked for 1st level grouping only. Please suggest modification that will allow items in any sub-groups, sub-sub-groups etc. to be displayed item wise. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will return the item wise stock by going through all the groups and the sub-groups within:

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <EXPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDESC>
                <REPORTNAME>Stock Summary</REPORTNAME>
                <STATICVARIABLES>
                    <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>ABC Ltd.</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                    <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:ASCII</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                    <SVFROMDate>20230401</SVFROMDate>
                    <SVTODATE>20231105</SVTODATE>
                    <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
                    <ISITEMWISE>Yes</ISITEMWISE>
                </STATICVARIABLES>
            </REQUESTDESC>
        </EXPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

The text of the response will contain all the inventory items as a text in CSV format.

SVCURRENTCOMPANY, SVFROMDate, SVTODATE are optional but preferable to know which data to expect in return, in case multiple companies are loaded or tally current date / system date / last entry date etc. don't match.